# Angular 6 reactive form control

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

i want to make a little homepage with angular 6. One part of it, are some tests like prime factorization and a test for leap-years. I made this with reactive forms for validation. My problem is, i can't execute both functions.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="primForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(primForm.value)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h3>Primfaktoren</h3>
      <label>Name:
        <input class="form-control" formControlName="zahl" placeholder="42" #spy>
      </label>
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="primForm.pristine || primForm.invalid" class="btn btn-success">Zerlegen</button>    
      <br>
      <div>Die Faktoren sind:</div>
      <br>
      <div style="display:inline" *ngFor="let faktor of faktoren">{{faktor}}</div>
      <br>
    </div>
    <p>{{spy.className}}</p>
  </form>

  <form [formGroup]="jahrForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(jahrForm.value)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h3>Schaltjahrtest</h3>
      <label>Jahr:
        <input class="form-control" formControlName="jahr" placeholder="2018" #spy1>
      </label>
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="jahrForm.pristine || jahrForm.invalid" class="btn btn-success">Prüfen</button>
      <p>{{jahr}} ist {{prf}} Schaltjahr</p>
    </div>
    <p>{{spy1.className}}</p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
}

  createForm() {
    this.primForm = this.fb.group({
      zahl: ['', Validators.min(3)]
    });
    this.jahrForm = this.fb.group({
      jahr: ['', Validators.min(1)]
    });
  }

  onSubmit(object: Object) {
    console.log(object, typeof object);

    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.primForm.dirty) {
      this.help = parseInt(object['zahl'], 10);
      this.ergebnis = this.primFaktor(this.help);
    } else {
      if (this.jahrForm.dirty) {
        this.help = parseInt(object['jahr'], 10);
        this.prf = this.jahrTest(this.help);
      }
    }
  }

  primFaktor(zahl: number): number[] {

    this.faktoren = [];
    let index = 2;

    while (zahl !== 1) {
      if (zahl % index === 0) {
        this.faktoren.push(index);
        zahl /= index;
        index = 2;
      } else {
        index++;
      }
    }
    return this.faktoren;
  }

  jahrTest(jahr: number): string {
    this.antwort = '';

    if (jahr % 4 === 0 && (jahr % 100 !== 0 || jahr % 400 === 0)) {
      this.antwort = 'ein';
    } else {
      this.antwort = 'kein';
    }
    return this.antwort;
  }
}
```

I can use the prim function but if i will use the year test, nothing happens and the page will crash.

I found nothing in the net.

Maybe someone has an idea or a workaround.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error.?

Comment: I can look for prime factors but if i try to get an answer for the year, the browser will crash. The year test without the prime test works.

Comment: what is the error in the console.?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Changed the typescript from:

```
onSubmit(object: Object) {
    console.log(object, typeof object);

    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.primForm.dirty) {
      this.help = parseInt(object['zahl'], 10);
      this.ergebnis = this.primFaktor(this.help);
    } else {
      if (this.jahrForm.dirty) {
        this.help = parseInt(object['jahr'], 10);
        this.prf = this.jahrTest(this.help);
      }
    }
  }
```

To:

```
const key = Object.keys(object);

    this.submitted = true;

    if (key[0] === 'zahl') {
      this.help = parseInt(object['zahl'], 10);
      this.ergebnis = this.primFaktor(this.help);
  } else {
      if (key[0] === 'jahr') {
       this.help = parseInt(object['jahr'], 10);
        this.prf = this.jahrTest(this.help);
     }
    }
  }
```

Now i get the key from the Object and the functions checks the key value.